# Let $f$ be an entire function such that $f(0)=0$. If $\displaystyle\lim_{|z|\to+\infty}v(z)=0,$ then $f\equiv 0$?

Tags: real-analysis, complex-analysis, analysis, metric-spaces, complex-integration

> For $z\in\mathbb{C}$, let $f(z)=u(z)+iv(z)$ be an entire function
> such that $f(0)=0$. Is that true that if
> $$\displaystyle\lim_{|z|\to+\infty}v(z)=0,$$ then $f\equiv 0$?

My attempt was to use the fact that $f$ is entire and therefore is analytic across the complex plane. Therefore, by Cauchy's Integral Formula, taking $\lambda$ a closed and simple path in $\mathbb{C}$, as $f(0)=0$, we have:
$$0=f(0)=\frac{1}{2\pi i}\int_\lambda\frac{f(z)}{z-0}dz\Rightarrow\int_\lambda\frac{f(z)}{z}dz=0.$$
But how can I conclude something about $f(z)$ using that $\displaystyle\lim_{|z|\to+\infty}v(z)=0$?

Comment: How about using Liouville's theorem(https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liouville%27s_theorem_(complex_analysis) )?

Comment: @Kaira That would be a great ideia, but how can I apply this theorem to my problem? :) Can you explain what you've thought?

Comment: “Integer function”? Perhaps you mean “entire function”?

Comment: @Manatee How about combining it with this question:https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2527579/an-entire-function-whose-imaginary-part-is-bounded-is-constant

Comment: @Kaira unfortunately I still don't see how these other statements can help me with my question :(

Comment: @Manatee The only part left is proving that $v$ is bounded. If $v$ is bounded then by the link I gave you, we can prove the statement. I think you can use the limit equation to prove that it is bounded.

Comment: @Kaira now I understand your thought. I'll think about how to show that the imaginary part is bounded. Do you have some idea?

Comment: @Manatee Start with the epsilon-delta definition of the limit equation. From that, it should be clear that $v$ is bounded in a certain region. For the other region, use the fact about the maximum/minimum of a continuous function.